# Return an array of all matched words

Tags: php

I have a function which replaces any word that looks like a link in a sting in php.

For example

```
$str = "Please go check out this link http://example.com and http://anothersite.com";

$link_replace = convert_link($str);

function convert_link($txt){
    $text = preg_replace('/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|[a-z0-9-_]\d{0,3}[.]|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $txt);
}
```

Please I want to only filter the words which are links and put them in an array, so I will have this

```
$link_array = array('http://example.com', 'http://anothersite.com');
```

Please how can I do this?

### Edit

I tried the `preg_match()`

```
preg_match('/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|[a-z0-9-_]\d{0,3}[.]|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/', $str, $txt);
print_r($txt);
```

But I only get this result

```
Array(
    [0] => http://example.com
    [1] => http://example.com
)
```

Comment: Read about `preg_match`

Comment: `preg_match_all()`

Comment: @u_mulder please look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
preg_match_all('/((http|https):\/\/[^\s'"]+)[\s"\<\>\\`\{\|\}\^]*/', $str, $matches);
```

$matches will be the nested array of matches. You should iterate it and get only [1] elements.